# BGP ASN Peer information sources

Tags: bgp, peering

So I know of the RIB files from RouteViews which can viewed using `BGPDump`. Now this data set will be easily able to show me the AS trace paths meaning I can find the `upstreams` for each ASN and their relative announced prefixes.

My question is: how do I go about finding all the ASN peers (which are not acting as upstreams) for example if an ASN has presence in an IX they will have a few upstreams a bunch of peers.

Example: http://bgp.he.net/AS2764#_graph4 as you can see here the ASN has 2 upstreams (same thing reflected in the raw RouteViews data dumps)

while : http://bgp.he.net/AS2764#_peers there a whole bunch of peers.

tl;dr where and how do I get my ends on dataset which shows the peers for ASNs

Comment: Hey, did you found a way to find the peers of an ASN?

Comment: @nacholibre There is no full proof way to get peers since in reality its not "public knowledge" per say, to increase exposure of peer stats you need to have presence in IXPs, a good datasource can be found on PCH (https://www.pch.net/) where they have prences in a whole load of internet exchanges and publish their BGP updates from their multiple locations

Answer (score 2):

You can check out http://www.cidr-report.org/as2.0/

Specific queries can be viewed using: http://www.cidr-report.org/cgi-bin/as-report?as=AS1299

Just replaced the above AS with the one you want to look up.

Comment: The link you posted only displayed the downstreams and upstream but not netrual peers.

Example:

http://bgp.he.net/AS45177#_peers and this 


http://www.cidr-report.org/cgi-bin/as-report?as=AS45177
As you can see here we have 25 upstreams and 35 downstream.


and on the HE.NET toolkit: BGP Peers Observed (v4): 765